# Number of successive up and down in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Say I have a time series like the one below.

I want to calculate the number of times returns (here, simply defined as X_n - X_{n-1}) were positive for 1 day, the number of times returns were positive for 2 straight days, ... etc .... and the same for negative returns.

What is an elegant way to do that? I tried different things using combining `diff()`, `sum()`, `cumsum()`, `groupby()` (etc...) but haven't really succeded.

Can you make suggestions, please?

```
DATE    SETTLE
24/05/1988  784
25/05/1988  759
26/05/1988  754
27/05/1988  768
31/05/1988  798
01/06/1988  802
02/06/1988  819
03/06/1988  849
06/06/1988  879
07/06/1988  882
08/06/1988  861
09/06/1988  886
10/06/1988  884
13/06/1988  877
14/06/1988  890
15/06/1988  920
16/06/1988  942
17/06/1988  972
20/06/1988  1002
21/06/1988  1047
22/06/1988  1055
23/06/1988  1033
24/06/1988  1030
27/06/1988  1060
28/06/1988  1015
29/06/1988  931
30/06/1988  986
01/07/1988  989
05/07/1988  959
06/07/1988  984
```

Comment: could you please provide an expected output, because it's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

First, convert your prices to returns:

```
df['daily_return'] = df.SETTLE.pct_change()
```

Then, calculate positive/negative daily return days:

```
df['pos_returns'] = df.daily_return.gt(0)  # or df.SETTLE.gt(df.SETTLE.shift())
df['neg_returns'] = df.daily_return.lt(0)
```

Create identifiers to group each series of returns by comparing the boolean flag to the prior flag (e.g. `(df.pos_returns != df.pos_returns.shift())`).  Take the cumulative sum of these to create groups of identical True/False ranges.  Mask out the False values by multiply by the flag, and take the positive group values.

Finally, perform `value_counts()` twice.  The first time aggregates the group by the day counts, and the second aggregates the day count occurrences.

```
pos_groups = (df.pos_returns != df.pos_returns.shift()).cumsum().mul(df.pos_returns)
consec_pos_return_days = pos_groups[pos_groups > 0].value_counts().value_counts()

neg_groups = (df.neg_returns != df.neg_returns.shift()).cumsum().mul(df.neg_returns)
consec_neg_return_days = neg_groups[neg_groups > 0].value_counts().value_counts()

>>> pd.concat([consec_pos_return_days, consec_neg_return_days], axis=1).fillna(0)
   pos_returns  neg_returns
1            3            2
2            1            4
7            2            0
```

The table indicates that there have been 3 single day positive returns, 1 two-day positive return and 2 seven-day positive returns.

Comment: following your reasoning, I also compute successive days of return = 0, that is df['even_ret'] = df.d_ret.eq(0); even_groups = (df.even_ret != df.even_ret.shift()).cumsum().mul(df.even_ret);
consec_even_ret_days = even_groups[even_groups > 0].value_counts().value_counts()

Answer (score 1):

I had code that was counting consecutive up days... this might help, and you can then filter the result of the consecutive days function. In the below mdo is just a wrapper around a dataframe:

```
def consdays(s):
    z=pandas.Series(index=s.index)
    for (i,j) in enumerate(s.index):
        if s.iloc[i]==1:
            z.iloc[i]=z.iloc[i-1]+1
        else:
            z.iloc[i]=0
    return z


def consecutivedays(mdo):
    x=mdo.df['close']
    yp=(x>=x.shift(1))*1
    ym=(x<x.shift(1))*1
    return consdays(yp)+-1*consdays(ym)
```